# Why averaging $3^m$ consecutive numbers always yields a whole number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, average

I think the title is self explanatory, but consider this equation:

$$ \frac {n+(n+1)+(n+2)}3 = A $$

where $A$ is always a whole number.

This is true for any $3^m$ numbers.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: Because 3 divides the numerator exactly.

Comment: More generally, if $m$ is any odd integer and $r$ is any integer, then any sequence of $rm$ consecutive integers has sum divisible by $m$. With $r=1$ the average will be an integer for any odd integer $m$. Since $m=3^k$ is an odd integer this will apply.

Comment: To conclude - averaging any odd number of consecutive numbers will yield a whole number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average of $$a,a+1,a+2,...,a+3^k-1$$ is the average of the first and the last  number. 
Thus the average is $$(a+a+3^k-1)/2=a+(3^k-1)/2$$ which is an integer because $3^k-1$ is always even.

Answer (score 2):

We can write the arithmetic mean of $3^k$ consecutive integers as $$A=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{3^k-1}(n+j)}{3^k}.$$
So $A\in\mathbb Z\iff 3^k\mid \sum_{j=0}^{3^k-1}(n+j)$.
But $$\sum_{j=0}^{3^k-1}(n+j)= \sum_{j=0}^{3^k-1}n+ \sum_{j=0}^{3^k-1}j=n3^k+\frac{3^k(3^k-1)}2=3^k(n+\frac{3^k-1}2) $$ where $2\mid 3^k-1 \; \forall k\in \mathbb N$. So we have our proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k$ be a positive integer.

The sum of $k$ consecutive integers whose first term is $v$ is
\begin{align*}
&v+(v+1)+\cdots + (v+(k-1))\\[4pt]
&=kv+\bigl(1+\cdots+(k-1)\bigr)\\[4pt]
&=kv+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\\[8pt]
&\text{hence the average is}\\[8pt]
&\frac{kv+{\large{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}}}{k}\\[4pt]
&=v+\frac{k-1}{2}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is an integer if and only if $k$ is odd.

In particular, since $3^m$ is odd, the average of $3^m$ consecutive integers is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$$n+(n+1)+(n+2)+\cdots(n+3^m-1)=\frac{3^m(2n+3^m-1)}{2}$$ is a multiple of $3^m$.

Comment: There is a missing $n3^x$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: yes, I am busy fixing.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with $3^m$. What really matters is that the number of terms is odd. Note that in every interval $n,\dots,n+(m-1)$ contains at least one integer $k$ that is a multiple of $m$. From there, notice that $(k-j)+(k+j)=2k$ is a multiple of $k$, and thus a multiple of $m$. If $k-j$ is in the interval but $k+j$ isn't, then $k+j-m$ is in the interval, and $(k-j)+(k+j-m)=2k-m$ is a multiple of $m$. Likewise, if $k-j$ isn't in the interval but $k+j$ is, then $k-j+m$ is in the interval, and $(k-j+m)+(k+j)=2k+m$ is a multiple of $m$. Furthermore, this covers the entire interval if $m$ is odd.

An explicit example of the above for $m=5$ and $n=9$:

\begin{align}9+10+11+12+13&=10+(9+11)+(12+13)\\&=\underbrace{2\times5}_k+\underbrace{2\times2\times5}_{2k}+\underbrace{2\times2\times5}_{2k+m}\end{align}

which is a multiple of $m$, which is $5$ here.

Comment: Even though this is not answering directly to the question, it is a good point to mention this will work for any odd amount of terms. Thanks

Comment: @ReaKrakover I fail to see how this doesn't answer the question, unless you are asking for a proof that $3^m$ is odd?

Comment: By "directly" i meant proving 3^x consecutive numbers.

Comment: What does "proving 3^x consecutive numbers" mean?